# WP Rest API not allowing to post anonymous comments through a Laravel request

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WP REST API to get posts in a Laravel project. Its not allowing to post anonymous comments against a specific post. I have updated my functions.php as well

Here is the error:

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_read_post","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to read the post for this comment.","data":{"sta (truncated...)
```

Api Class:

```
public static function postComments($postId, $author_name, $author_email, $content){

    $url = config::get('app.WP_BASE_URL') . '/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?author_name='. $author_name.'&author_email='. $author_email.'&content='. $content.'&post='. $postId;

    $params = [
        'post' => $postId,
        'author_email' => $author_email,
        'author_name' => $author_name,
        'content' => $content
    ];

    $data = Wpapi::curlPostRequest($url, $params);

    return $data;

}
```

Controller:

```
public function postComment(Request $request){

  $id = $request->input('id');

  $data = $request->validate([
  'name' => 'required|max:255',
  'email' => 'required',
  'comment' => 'required',
  ]);
$author_email = $data['email'];
$author_name = $data['name'];
$content = $data['comment'];

      $postComment = Wpapi::postComments($id, $author_name, $author_email, $content );

    if($postComment){
      echo "Success";
    }
    else {
      echo "Failure";
    }
```

}

Comment: Hey Kashif, Are you passing any authorization with the Post request?

Comment: No, I'm not passing any authorization through the post request.

Comment: The authorization would be needed in order to post the comment.
Can you add the spinet of the request you are trying to do?

Comment: I have added the snippet

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**
Like the GET request, You can use the POST request as well to post data. What you need to do is to pass the authorization headers with the POST API call. 
You can get more detail about the authorization mechanism here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

**Headers:**

```
Authorization:Bearer <token>
Content-Type:application/json
```

Headers you will need to pass into the Params Array.

**Solution 2:**
If you want to post a comment as Anonymous User than follow the below steps:
 Open your WordPress theme’s **functions.php**, and add the following snippet:

```
add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );
```

And than try to run the Snippet that you have coded already. I would suggest to use the Solution 1.

Comment: Glad to hear that @KashifRaza.

Comment: Thanks ! How to pass metada ? I'm gettting a 401 with 'Sorry, you are not allowed to edit the *** custom field.' ...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, extends `WP_REST_Comments_Controller`.

```php
class ClassWpRestCommentsModController extends WP_REST_Comments_Controller {
  public function create_item_permissions_check($request) {
    // just add/modify the permissions check here
  }
}
```

Then, register a new router using `(new ClassWpRestCommentsModController())->create_item`. You can even add your own permissions check to it, ie. reCaptcha.

Source code here: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/master/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-comments-controller.php