# How to Create a comment using WP Rest API v2?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to create a new comment via the WP Rest APi v2 using a `POST` request to the following url:

```
https://www.turboweb.online/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?author_email=admin@admin.com&author_name=alex bhati&content=nice post&post=4002
```

But, this is the response I'm getting every time:

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden_param",
    "message": "Query parameter not permitted: author_email",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **author_email** field requires authorization in order to be added, maybe this answer can help: [WP Rest API not allowing to post anonymous comments through a Laravel request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395025/wp-rest-api-not-allowing-to-post-anonymous-comments-through-a-laravel-request)